# How to make Simapro output datasets compatible with ecoinvent?

Tags: brightway

I need to link a Simapro output dataset with the ecoinvent database.
Unfortunately due to permanent changes between these 2 databases, the
code I use (Brightway) is not able to do a correct migration from one
database to the other.

Has anyone ever worked on this problem ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposal to ease the migration with Brightway from Simapro to ecoinvent. (but the code that is proposed in section 2. below to make the correspondance is generic and can be applied to any other databases).

1. read your Simapro dataset and export it in a .xlsx file :

```py
from brightway2 import *

simapro_db= SimaProCSVImporter(fname, name) # fname is the pathname of your simapro .csv file
simapro_db.write_excel()
```

2. Apply the code (see below) which is in charge of finding the best matching between the simapro and the ecoinvent database names. (this could take a while, depending on the size of your simapro dataset).
   When ending, have a look on the generated output file (output.xlsx).
   Elements with low scoring (typically < 90%) has to be analysed and replaced if needed.
   Finally, have a global reviewing to detect fake hight-scored correspondances.
3. To perform the migration in Brightway, Replace the file "SimaPro - ecoinvent - biosphere.xlsx" in bw2io.data.lci by the modified output.xlsx obtained in 2. Then run:

```py
from bw2io.data import convert_simapro_ecoinvent_elementary_flows

convert_simapro_ecoinvent_elementary_flows()
```

**Here is the python code that realizes the matching between Simapro and ecoinvents names.**
During the process, for each Simapro element that differ from ecoinvent syntax, the simapro name and its corresponding evoinvent one are written with potentially the ecoinvent synonym at the origin of the best matching score.

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
from thefuzz import process, fuzz

# fname = ... # the pathname related to the .xlsx file generated at the 1rst step
# fname_ref = ... # the pathname related to the ecoinvent database (.xlsx file)


print("Extract Names to match (Simapro)")
dfr = pd.read_excel(fname, header=1)
names = dfr.query('Matched==False')['Name'].tolist()
categories = dfr.query('Matched==False')['Categories'].tolist()

print("Extract Reference Names (ecoinvent)")
dfr_ref = pd.read_excel(fname_ref, sheet_name='Elementary Exchanges',
                        usecols=['Name', 'Compartment', 'Synonym'])
names_ref = {}
for comp in ['natural resource', 'air', 'water', 'soil']:
    vals = dfr_ref.query(f'Compartment=="{comp}"')['Name']
    names_ref.update({comp: vals.tolist()})

print("Extract Synonyms Names")
dfr_ref = dfr_ref.set_index(['Name', 'Compartment'])
dfr_ref = dfr_ref.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('\n').explode())
dfr_ref = dfr_ref.reset_index()

names_ref_syn = {}
for comp in ['natural resource', 'air', 'water', 'soil']:
    vals_syn = dfr_ref.query(f'Compartment=="{comp}"')['Synonym']
    names_ref_syn.update({comp: vals_syn.dropna().tolist()})

print("Search for matching")
results = []
ntot = len(names)
name_previous = ''
category_previous = ''

for i, (name, category) in enumerate(zip(names, categories)):

    ok = True
    if "Resources" in category:
        category = 'natural resource'
    elif "Emissions" in category:
        category = category.replace('Emissions to ', '')
        category = category.split(":")[0]
    else:
        ok = False
        print(f"FAILED : {name}, {category}")

    if ok and (name, category) != (name_previous, category_previous):
        out = process.extract(name, names_ref[category])[0]
        (name_ref, score) = out

        # correct scoring
        score = fuzz.ratio(name, name_ref)

        # search in synonyms if not perfect matching
        if score != 100:
            out_syn = process.extract(name, names_ref_syn[category])[0]
            (name_ref_syn, score_syn) = out_syn

            if score_syn > score:
                # assign the name_ref related to the synonym
                dfr_name = dfr_ref.query(f'Synonym=="{name_ref_syn}"')['Name']
                name_ref = dfr_name.values[0]
                res = [category, name, name_ref, name_ref_syn, score_syn]
            else:
                res = [category, name, name_ref, '', score]

            results.append(res)
            print(f"{i + 1}/{ntot}: {name} --> {res[2]} / {res[3]} ({res[4]})")

        (name_previous, category_previous) = (name, category)

simapro_categ = {'natural resource': 'Resources',
                 'air': 'Emissions to air',
                 'water': 'Emissions to water',
                 'soil': 'Emissions to soil'}
results_simapro = [[simapro_categ[cat], name, name_ref, name_ref_syn, score]
                   for (cat, name, name_ref, name_ref_syn, score) in results]

columns = columns = ['SimaPro category', 'SimaPro', 'Ecoinvent 3',
                     'Synonym', 'Score']
dfr_res = pd.DataFrame(results_simapro, columns=columns)
dfr_res.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)
```

Here is an example of printing during the execution
[image]

Comment: Thank you Patrick it helps! Of course a check and a bit of manual work has to be done after.

Comment: Thanks. Note that to work, the last action in the proposal requires the following fix: https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/pull/204